# R:How to display city level data on map and how to ZOOM it on one specific region of the map

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-analysis, choropleth, usmap

I am using usmap and ggplot to plot population on a map. My data has two columns - population and zipcodes.

Question: How can I display data on city level  using the same libraries or if you know of other libraries that can do the job.

Question: I am plotting California map and I want to zoom on LA county and nearby counties.

Below code gives me a nice California map and population as a color.

```
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

usmap::plot_usmap("counties", 
              include = ("CA") )

plot_usmap(data = data, values = "pop_2015", include = c("CA"), color = "grey") + 
theme(legend.position = "right")+scale_fill_gradient(trans = "log10")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tigris` package makes downloading zip code tabulation areas fairly simple. You can download as a simple features dataframe so joining your data by zip code using `dplyr` functions is fairly easy. Here is a quick example:

```r
library(tigris)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- zctas(cb = TRUE,
            starts_with = c("778"), 
            class = "sf")

## generate some sample data that
## can be joined to the downloaded data
sample_data <- tibble(zips = df$ZCTA5CE10,
                      values = rnorm(n = df$ZCTA5CE10))


## left join the sample data to the downloaded data
df <- df %>%
  left_join(sample_data, 
            by = c("ZCTA5CE10" = "zips"))

## plot something
ggplot(df) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = values))
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: I tried joining them and it throws this error - Error: Can't join on 'zip' x 'ZCTA5CE10' because of incompatible types (numeric / character) . I also converted both columns using as.numeric but did not work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @miss_belle The ZCTA5CE10 variable in the downloaded dataset is specified as a character type. It sounds like your zip variable is numeric. Try something along the lines of `your_data <- your_data %>% mutate(zip = as.character(zip))`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Tirgris is a great library. I liked it over choroplethrzip. I also added labels to the map city names for respective zip codes using geom_sf_label